# How to get 5 result from fuzzy match gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fuzzy-search

Now, i am using gem https://github.com/seamusabshere/fuzzy_match, but it only take 1 result for 1 call time. How do i can get 5 result instead ?
This is my code:

```
def related_ques
  collect_ques = Question.joins(:question_topics)
                 .where("topic_id in (?) and questions.id != ?",self.topic_ids, self.id)
  results = Array.new
  Settings.question_page.num_related_ques.times do
    fz = FuzzyMatch.new(collect_ques, read: :title)
    question = fz.find(self.title)
    results << question unless question.nil?
    collect_ques = collect_ques.to_a - [question]
  end
 results
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `fuzzy_match` gem, You will have multiple result from `find` only when there are multiple string matching to the given input. You should go through [this](http://numbers.brighterplanet.com/2012/01/18/fuzzy-match-in-ruby/) documentation for more information.

Comment: its sound terrible, now i must initialize fuzzy object then find, after that excluse founded item from collection and continue initialize new fuzzy object with new collection. @_@ .Do it have any option for 5 results approximately result.